# How to work around NotMapped properties in queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have method that looks like this:

```
    private static IEnumerable<OrganizationViewModel> GetOrganizations()
    {
        var db = new GroveDbContext();

        var results = db.Organizations.Select(org => new OrganizationViewModel
        {
            Id = org.OrgID,
            Name = org.OrgName,
            SiteCount = org.Sites.Count(),
            DbSecureFileCount = 0,
            DbFileCount = 0
        });

        return results;
    }
```

This is returns results pretty promptly.

However, you'll notice the OrganizationViewModel has to properties which are getting set with "0".  There are properties in the Organization model which I added via a partial class and decorated with [NotMapped]: UnsecureFileCount and SecureFileCount.

If I change those 0s to something useful...

```
   DbSecureFileCount = org.SecureFileCount,
   DbFileCount = org.UnsecureFileCount
```

... I get the "Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported" exception.  I find this a little confusing because I don't feel I'm asking the database about them, I'm only setting properties of the view model.

However, since EF isn't listening to my argument I tried a different approach:

```
    private static IEnumerable<OrganizationViewModel> GetOrganizations()
    {
        var db = new GroveDbContext();

        var results = new List<OrganizationViewModel>();
        foreach (var org in db.Organizations)
        {
            results.Add(new OrganizationViewModel
            {
                Id = org.OrgID,
                Name = org.OrgName,
                DbSecureFileCount = org.SecureFileCount,
                DbFileCount = org.UnsecureFileCount,
                SiteCount = org.Sites.Count()
            });
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Technically this gives me the correct results without an exception but it takes forever. (By "forever" I mean more than 60 seconds whereas the first version delivers results in  under a second.)

Is there a way to optimize the second approach?  Or is there a way to get the first approach to work?

Comment: The second method will take longer because it will be bringing your organizations into memory, rather than letting your database handle the query. I've hit this issue in the past as well, and I'm afraid I've not found a solution for it either.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to load the values back as an anonymous type and the loop through those to load your  viewmodel (n+1 is most likely the reason for the slowness).

For example:

```
var results = db.Organizations.Select(org => new
        {
            Id = org.OrgID,
            Name = org.OrgName,
            DbSecureFileCount = org.SecureFileCount,
            DbFileCount = org.UnsecureFileCount,
            SiteCount = org.Sites.Count()
        }).ToList();

var viewmodels = results.Select( x=> new OrganizationViewModel
{
    Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        DbSecureFileCount = x.DbSecureFileCount,
        DbFileCount = x.DbFileCount,
        SiteCount = x.SiteCount
});
```

Sorry about the formatting; I'm typing on a phone.

Comment: This doesnt change anything.  That act of having the two additional non-mapped properties in .Select is what causes the error, not the view model.  I tried what you said and it did indeed cause the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically lazy loading each object at each iteration of the loop, causing n+1 queries.

What you should do is bring in the entire collection into memory, and use it from there.

Sample code:

```
var organizationList = db.Organizations.Load();
foreach (var org in organizationList.Local)
    {
       //Here you are free to do whatever you want
    }
```